# JupyterHub LocalAuthenticator does not work

Tags: authentication, pam, jupyterhub

I am trying to configure and understnad how the most common Jupyter authenticators work. However, I am having trouble understanding how `LocalAuthenticator` works and how it differs from `PAMAuthenticator`. The Jupyter documentation states the following: `The LocalAuthenticator is a special kind of authenticator that has the ability to manage users on the local system.`. Given that I am running everything locally, on my laptop, my uderstading is that I can use the same credentials I use to login to my Linux user. However this doesn't work. The JupyterHub server gives the following message: `Failed login for <user>`.

My JupyterHub configuration file only contains the following line:

`c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'jupyterhub.auth.LocalAuthenticator'`.

If I change the above line to:

`c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'jupyterhub.auth.PAMAuthenticator'`

then everything works just fine and the login is succesfull.

Can someone explain me the differences of the two authenticators and why the `LocalAuthenticator` does not work in my case? The only difference I am aware of is that (according to the documentation) the `LocalAuthenticator` creates new users if they don't exist. However, after setting `c.LocalAuthenticator.create_system_users = True` and trying to login with a non-existent user, no new user is created.

Thank you.

PS: My OS is Debian Testing and I have installed JupyterHub using the instructions provided on its GitHub page.

Comment: same problem here :(

Comment: Actually, `PAMAuthenticator` is a subclass of `LocalAuthenticator`, if you look into the class's documentations.